# QueryDSL: Use a JPASubQuery in JPAQuery.from()

Tags: java, querydsl

i have an SQL like:

#### Query 1:

```
  SELECT
    t.name,
    sum(t.value)
  FROM
    myTable t
  WHERE 
    -- conditions...
  GROUP BY 
    t.name
  HAVING sum(t.value) >= 100
```

and i have:

#### Query 2:

```
  select count(*) from (
   -- QUERY1
) as countQuery
```

And i'm trying to do it on QueryDSL.
I already have my Query 1 as an JPAQuery.
Now a need to use it as a subquery, so i'm trying to do something like:

```
JPASubQuery subQuery = new JPASubQuery(query1.getMetadata());
new JPAQuery().from(subquery).count();
```

But it's not possible to add a SubQuery in the FROM clause.

It would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it's not possible due to JPA limitations:

https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1471